# Integral of greatest integer function divided by an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer not exceeding $x$, then find $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{e^{x}} dx$. The correct answer is supposed to be $\frac{1}{e-1}$.

In order to wrap my head around this problem, I wanted to see if there was a pattern for what was going on for each of the integrals $\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\displaystyle \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{e^{x}}dx$. Each one is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{n(e-1)}{e^{n+1}}$. I figured then that a good way to solve this problem, then, was to sum up the infinite series, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n(e-1)}{e^{n+1}}$.

Now, I believe that this series must converge, since the trapezoids formed by the x-axis and each $\displaystyle \frac{n}{e^{x}}$ become infinitesimally small as $n$ gets large. However, it's not a geometric series, so I am not sure how to find what it converges to, which, from the answer to the problem, must be $\frac{1}{e-1}$.

Am I going about this in an unnecessarily complicated way, and is there a simpler method to evaluate this integral? If not, what is the piece that I'm missing? Thanks :)

Comment: What do you get if you differentiate the identity (for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$) $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\,?$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$?

Comment: Right. And now look at your series, whether you can recognise that in it.

Comment: Meh, kind of, except the exponent in my series is $-(n+1)$ if you rewrite it in that form.

Comment: I'm trying to make a substitution to get around that, but what happens to your index when you do that?

Comment: $n+1 = (n-1) + 2$. There's a constant difference, you can just pull that factor out.

Comment: Ooh, very clever! I think that should do it! Thanks! I think I need to review my series expansions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way is fine, it's just a matter of recognising a differentiated geometric series in that:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(e-1)}{e^{n+1}} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e-1}{e^2} \cdot \frac{n}{e^{n-1}}\\
&= \frac{e-1}{e^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n-1}\\
&= \frac{e-1}{e^2} \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)^2}\\
&= \frac{e-1}{(e-1)^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{e-1}.
\end{align}$$

In a similar way, when you have a series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)\cdot x^{n+d}$$

with a polynomial $p$ of degree $k$, then you can write that as a linear combination of derivatives of the geometric series with ratio $x$ of orders $\leqslant k$.

Answer (score 3):

Our integral is
$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty \left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)e^{-x}\,dx.\tag{1}$$
The first integral in (1) has value $1$. For the second integral, split as you did as a sum of integrals
$$\int_n^{n+1} (x-n)e^{-x}\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get $\frac{e-2}{e}e^{-n}$. Summing from $0$ to $\infty$ we get $\frac{e-2}{e-1}$.
Thus the expression (1) is equal to $1-\frac{e-2}{e-1}$, which is $\frac{1}{e-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Another method consists in using a Fourier series :

[image]

Of course, it's not so easy, but it's a nice exercise !